# React Native: Flipper cannot connect to Metro on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler, flipper

### Problem

I am trying to run my app via a connected device on Mac and debug it using Flipper, but it does not work.

### Information

My app connects to Flipper, but can't connect to Metro. If I retry the connection, it says that no apps are connected to Metro. I use xCode to start the app, which works, but there seems indeed to be an issue with Metro. If I try to reload in the terminal running it, it says no apps are connected. But hot-reloading works and I see on error messages anywhere (I guess due to the fact that they would appear in Flipper).

### What I tried so far

I am really at a loss here and tried for endless hours now:

- Flipper has the same version as specified in the Podfile
- I changed the port where Metro runs
- Tried starting via `npx react-native start`
- Removed the cache / reinstalled / ...